# Obtener nombres de archivos correctamente

Tags: jscript

El siguiente JScript para un botón de un explorador de archivos tiene como intención buscar, de forma recursiva, los archivos y carpetas que posean alguna etiqueta, y mostrar el resultado en el panel Utilidades del propio explorador.

El script funciona bien en el sentido de encontrar correctamente todas las etiquetas existentes, pero no informa correctamente cuál es el archivo que posee cada etiqueta, siempre especifica el mismo archivo, el último archivo de la carpeta, tenga este etiqueta o no?

En la imagen a continuación podemos ver que el archivo 1 posee la etiqueta "Ok", y el archivo 3, la etiqueta "Favorito", sin embargo en el resultado se informa que el archivo 4 es el que posee las dos etiquetas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function OnClick(clickData) {
    var cmd = clickData.func.command;
    var tab = clickData.func.sourcetab;
    var fsu = DOpus.FSUtil();
    var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    var labelSet = DOpus.Create().StringSet();
    cmd.deselect = false;
    
    function GetLabelsFromItem(item) {
        var itemLabels = item.Labels();
        if (typeof itemLabels == 'undefined') return;
        if (itemLabels.count == 0) return;
        for (var e = new Enumerator(itemLabels); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
            labelSet.insert(e.item());
        }
    }
    
    cmd.RunCommand('Set UTILITY=otherlog');
    DOpus.ClearOutput();
    for (var e = new Enumerator(tab.all); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
        var item = e.item();
        if (item.is_dir) {
            var folderEnum = fsu.ReadDir(item, 'r')
            while (!folderEnum.complete) {
                var folderItem = folderEnum.Next();
                if (folderItem.is_dir) continue;
                GetLabelsFromItem(folderItem);
            }
        } else {
            GetLabelsFromItem(item);
        }
    }

    //Mostrar resultado en el panel Utilidades
    DOpus.Output('ETIQUETAS\n');
    if (labelSet.empty) {
            DOpus.Output('< ninguna >');
    } else {
        for (var e = new Enumerator(labelSet); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
            DOpus.Output(item.realpath); //Ruta completa del archivo
            DOpus.Output(e.item()); //Etiqueta 
            DOpus.Output(""); //Línea en blanco para separar resultados
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estás guardando las etiquetas encontradas, pero el el item donde las encontraste. La variable item está declarada dentro del bucle for, por lo que que el valor final es el del último item recorrido. Por curiosidad: Este código es javascript antiguo, verdad? Hace años que no veía el uso de `ActiveXObject`

Comment: Gracias @Pablo Lozano por la respuesta, y sí, el código es bien antiguo, ja ja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta de @bytespiller desde otro sitio. Mi eterna gratitud!!!

```
var filesWithLabels = DOpus.Create.Map();
filesWithLabels(item.realpath) = itemLabels;

//Mostrar resultado en el panel Utilidades
DOpus.Output('ETIQUETAS\n');
if (labelSet.empty) {
    DOpus.Output('< ninguna >');
} else {
    for (var e = new Enumerator(filesWithLabels); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
        var filepath = e.item(); // key
        var labels = filesWithLabels(filepath); // values
        DOpus.Output(filepath);

        var strLabels = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < labels.count; i++) {
            strLabels += labels(i) + ", ";
        }
        strLabels = strLabels.slice(0, -2); // Gets rid of final comma & space ", "

        DOpus.Output(strLabels);
        DOpus.Output("");
    }
}
}
```